# How to animate a custom Leaflet marker along a route?

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

I am very much new to leaflet and i hope that someone can help me.
What im trying to do is adding two markers on the map and make another marker follow the route.

I have found a few plugins that would help but these plugins makes your marker over the map and not follow a specific route. 
http://ewoken.github.io/Leaflet.MovingMarker/

I know how it is done in google maps but not in leaflet. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zbr-F9wVqgU

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close. You choosed the Leaflet plugin and have quite a precise goal.
You just have to follow what is explained [here](https://github.com/ewoken/Leaflet.MovingMarker).

Let's implement that :

```
// here is the path (get it from where you want)
var coordinateArray = [ [0,1], [1,1], [1,0] ];
// or for example
var coordinateArray = existingPolyline.getLatLngs();
// here is the line you draw (if you want to see the animated marker path on the map)
var myPolyline = L.polyline(coordinateArray);
myPolyline.addTo(map);
// i don't know if i understood your question correctly
// if you want to put a marker at the beginning and at the end of the path :
var mstart = L.marker(coordinateArray[0]).addTo(map);
var mend = L.marker(coordinateArray[coordinateArray.length - 1]).addTo(map);
// here is the moving marker (6 seconds animation)
var myMovingMarker = L.Marker.movingMarker(coordinateArray, 6000, {
    autostart: false
});
map.addLayer(myMovingMarker);
myMovingMarker.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

As none of the Leaflet plugins to animate markers are maintained, I suggest to implement your own playback solution:

```js
const leafletMap = L.map(document.getElementById("leaflet-container")).setView([0, 0], 1);


const dataset = [{
  lng: -100,
  lat: -80,
  timestamp: new Date().getTime()
}];
let timestamp = 1710067901850;

for (let i = 1; i < 300; i++) {
  dataset.push({
    lng: dataset[i - 1].lng + Math.random(),
    lat: dataset[i - 1].lat + Math.random(),
    timestamp: dataset[i - 1].timestamp + 500
  });
};

let marker = L.marker(dataset[0], { icon: new L.Icon({ iconUrl: '/marker.svg', iconSize: [20, 20], iconAnchor: [10, 20] }) });
marker.addTo(leafletMap);

let path = L.polyline(dataset[0]);
path.addTo(leafletMap);


let tick = dataset[0].timestamp;
const endTime = dataset[dataset.length - 1].timestamp;

let interval;
function start() {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (tick > endTime) {
      // End of animation: leave tracks and markers where they are but stop intervals
      stop();
    } else {
      // Create or update the marker
      moveMarker();

      // Update tick including speed
      tick += 500;
    }
  }, 100);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  tick = dataset[0].timestamp;
  marker.setLatLng(dataset[0]);
}

function moveMarker() {
  // Look for the timestamp just before tick
  let closestPointIndex = -1;
  for (let i = 0; i < dataset.length && closestPointIndex < 0; i += 1) {
    const timestamp = dataset[i].timestamp;
    if (timestamp > tick) {
      closestPointIndex = i === 0 ? 0 : i - 1;
    }
  }
  marker.setLatLng(dataset[closestPointIndex]);
  path.setLatLngs(dataset.slice(0, closestPointIndex + 1));
}

function pause() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}

function setCursor(time) {
  tick = parseInt(time);
  moveMarker();
}
```

```css
button {
  background-color: slateblue;
  border: 1px solid skyblue;
  color: lightblue;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <section style="display: flex; width: 200px; margin: auto">
      <button
        onclick="start()"
        style="border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px; font-size: 1.5em"
      >
        ▶
      </button>
      <button
        onclick="pause()"
        style="border-radius: 0"
      >
        ❚❚
      </button>
      <button
        onclick="stop()"
        style="border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0; font-size: 2em; padding-top: 2px"
      >
        ■
      </button>   
    </section>

    <div id="leaflet-container" style="width: 70vw; height: 70vh; margin: 50px auto"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="leaflet-animate.js"></script>
</html>
```

From this [article](https://dev.to/bcaure/animated-traveling-map-with-leaflet-5fdf).

Comment: yes sorry, it's a typo